# XCUITest: Clicking "Choose" for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, xcuitest

I am testing UIImagePickerController with allowsEditing = true on XCode 12.4 (Simulator iPhone 11). 
I am at the below stage and trying to click the "Choose" button. Since it is out of the app context the "Choose" button is not clickable somehow. (I know it doesn't make sense).

[image]

 
 
**What is done so far!**

```
// open the UIImagePickerController 
app.sheets.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Gallery"].tap()

// Select the 2nd image which opens the edit view
app.images.element(boundBy: 1).tap()

// How to select "Choose" button?
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Getting the button by index

```
app.buttons.element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

This gives errror:
*Button, label: 'calendar', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 6865, elementOrHash.elementID: 140369982962640.396. (Underlying Error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 6865, elementOrHash.elementID: 140369982962640.396)*

2)

```
app.buttons["Choose"].tap()
```

It doesn't actually click the "Choose" button, so the editing view doesn't get hidden.

Here are the logs for taapping a Choose button

*t =    37.13s Tap "Choose" Button

t =    37.13s     Wait for com.rc.tkm to idle

t =    37.20s     Find the "Choose" Button

t =    37.37s     Check for interrupting elements affecting "Choose" Button

t =    37.43s     Synthesize event

t =    37.55s     Wait for com.rc.tkm to idle*

Also, the Recording functionality also doesn't work. It crashes when I click on the "Choose" button.


**EDIT 1 (11th June, 2021)**

I have decided to switch to PHPickerViewController and implement my own cropping functionallity. But the weird thing now happens.
When I select 3 images in the PHPicker, only 2 images are successfully available in the delegate and 1 image gives error. 

Here is my delegate:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        let itemProviders = results.map(\.itemProvider)
        for itemProvider in itemProviders {
            if itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
                    if let image = image as? UIImage  {  
                      // Get images twice, but error once
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error

```
Optional<Error>
  - some : Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001cc2e80 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/arjav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5BE27527-2C05-4203-A2CE-0546D25513E5/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/95ACE2D1-631F-4EFA-A19A-361C34E8F332/File%20Provider%20Storage/photospicker/version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg, NSFilePath=/Users/arjav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5BE27527-2C05-4203-A2CE-0546D25513E5/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/95ACE2D1-631F-4EFA-A19A-361C34E8F332/File Provider Storage/photospicker/version=1&uuid=CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3&mode=compatible.jpeg, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001cc3f60 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}}
```

It seems to be a simulator issue. I have found similar bug on [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653993)

Comment: What do you see when you have break for for app.buttons["Choose"].tap() and do po XCUIApplication().debugDescription

Comment: You can check the output here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18Ywr4ji1OfbwnUqy-ezYT-6AZNt47s3a57fWsYLQXl0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do not test Apple. Test _you_.

Comment: @matt Do you mean I should mock PHPickerViewController for ui testing? That doesn't seem right. Especially since after selecting 3 images from picker I am getting only 2 images and an error for the 3rd image.

Comment: I’m at a loss since your debug does show a `Button` labeled “Choose”.

Comment: Want to make sure , You are XCUIApplication Target ID Should be "com.rc.tkm" and XCUIApplication().Activate.  For Choose button -  XCUIApplication().ScrollView().buttons("'Choose").FirstMatch and Tap()

Comment: @MikeCollins That's why I switched to PHPickerViewController. Apple is not treating xcuitest as a first class citizen. In Xcode 12.5 the whole recording test system is broken. (Reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679380)

Comment: @matt Correct, "com.rc.tkm" is the target id. Tried tapping the button with your logic, but still not working.

Comment: @ArjavDave yikes! Thanks for the info. I don't ever use the recorder, but some folks I'm training up do so I'll be sure to let them know to not upgrade.